# Azure autoscale metricname values

Tags: azure, autoscaling

I need to define scale rule for my virtual machine I have read the following

> The MetricName and MetricNamespace are not values I just made up.
> These have to be precise.  You can get these values from the
> MetricsClient API and there is some sample code in this link to show
> how to get the values.
>
> http://rickrainey.com/2013/12/15/auto-scaling-cloud-services-on-cpu-percentage-with-the-windows-azure-monitoring-services-management-library/

But its still not clear ho do I get a MetricName list of possible values as I didn't found any sample code for it

Comment: Yakov, thanks for reading my blog. :)  I was going to paste in the code I used to get the MetricName.  However, it doesn't work now.   I updated the libraries and still was unsuccessful.  I'll look into this more to see if I can get it working and post the answer then.

Comment: Just tried this again and it worked.  Must have been an issue with Azure earlier.  I'm posting the answer shortly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I used to get the available MetricNames for the cloud service.  It was part of a unit test project, hence the [TestMethod] attribute.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task GetMetricDefinitions()
    {
        // Build the resource ID string.
        string resourceId = ResourceIdBuilder.BuildCloudServiceResourceId(
            cloudServiceName, deploymentName, roleName );

        Console.WriteLine("Resource Id: {0}", resourceId);

        //Get the metric definitions.
        var retrieveMetricsTask =
            metricsClient.MetricDefinitions.ListAsync(resourceId, null, null, CancellationToken.None);
        var metricListResponse = await retrieveMetricsTask;

        MetricDefinitionCollection metricDefinitions = metricListResponse.MetricDefinitionCollection;

        // Make sure something was returned.
        Assert.IsTrue(metricDefinitions.Value.Count > 0);

        // Display the metric definitions.
        int count = 0;
        foreach (MetricDefinition metricDefinition in metricDefinitions.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MetricDefinitio: " + count++);
            Console.WriteLine("Display Name: " + metricDefinition.DisplayName);
            Console.WriteLine("Metric Name: " + metricDefinition.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Metric Namespace: " + metricDefinition.Namespace);
            Console.WriteLine("Is Altertable: " + metricDefinition.IsAlertable);
            Console.WriteLine("Min. Altertable Time Window: " + metricDefinition.MinimumAlertableTimeWindow);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Here is the output of the test for my cloud service:

[image]

Comment: I wonder why Microsoft just don't give such list as part of their documentation?